# Why does the Linux Open system call not need a buffer size parameter for the path?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, system-calls, api-design

Why does the `open` system call not need a buffer size parameter like the `write` system call does?

How do these two system calls treat their string parameters differently?

Does the `open` system call assume a zero-terminated string for the path parameter while the `write` system call does not? If so why the inconsistency?

Why not make all (or none) of the system calls that use strings / arrays require a size parameter?

Comment: It's a normal 0 terminated string, yes, while `write()` can be used for data that's not.

Comment: open needs a zero terminated filename (zero bytes are _not_ valid in filenames). write writes _binary_ data, so zero bytes can occur and thus cannot work as buffer terminator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNIX was developed as an operating system for programs written in assembly, later for programs written in C.  In the assembly convention the UNIX team uses and later in C, strings are terminated with NUL bytes.  Thus it is only natural to use the same convention when talking to the operating system.  Linus copied the UNIX API when designing Linux, so that's why it has the same design.  No functionality is lost by terminating strings with NUL as NUL bytes are not allowed to appear in paths or other identifiers.

A `write` call writes arbitrary binary data to a file.  This data is not necessarily text thus using the string convention doesn't make much sense.

Comment: ` No functionality is lost by terminating strings with NUL as NUL bytes are not allowed to appear in paths or other identifiers.` well, this is exactly functionality lost - since strings are null-terminated, Unix doesn't allow null bytes in identifiers. While I do not think it is a big loss, and I know of no OS which allows that, formally, your statement is internally contradictive.

Comment: Ha! The write being used for binary data rather than strings was the source of my misunderstanding. Every time I've used the write system call so far I've done so with a string argument and so I had not considered that you may want to use the write syscall to write bytes that don't actually make sense within a string such as a NULL. When I look at it as the buffer argument for write not being a string it starts making sense. thanks.

Comment: @SergeyA There is no contradiction; if someone was to make a UNIX-variant where paths were passed as buffer/length pairs, you could still not create files with names containing NUL bytes as that's prohibited by the POSIX standard.

Comment: @fuz That's a bit of circular reasoning, though.  A lot of what's now the POSIX standard is really just codification of how things were done in early Unix variants.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You view this from the perspective of “we could have more functionality if the design decision was made differently back in the day” while I see this as “changing the interface today would not give more functionality.”  Both positions are correct, but I don't think it's useful to think about what could have been in this case.